# Get All object from a list <object> which id contains in List<long>

Tags: java, collections, comparison, java-6

How can i get `List<Object> filteredList`  whose id (`Object.id`) contains in a given `List<id> idsList` from another `List<Object>allObjects`.
what will be the effective and efficient way in terms of time to solve this considering a moderate data volume.

I am using java6

Comment: Well you better start working on it then.  Stack Overflow is not a request/fulfill type of site... it'a a Q and A site

Comment: Off-topic:There's rarely such thing as "universal most efficient". It depends on actual usage

Comment: Please at least mention which Java version you are using

Comment: Also, please don't use Indian words / measurements, like "size in lac". There are perfectly good universal measurements to be used instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't want to iterate both the list so many times

Why? Premature optimisation is a bad thing. Test it first, measure whether it is efficient enough, and address the problem *if it exists*.

You can accomplish this with streams using a simple filter:

```
class Student
{
    long id;
}

final List<Student> students = /*something*/;
final List<Long> rollNoList = /*something*/;

List<Student> newStudents = students.stream()
                                    .filter(student -> rollNoList.contains(student.id))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The advantage of doing it with streams is that you may be able to parallelise it later.

---

An additional optimisation would be to examine your use of data structures. As [Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose) points out, using something like a `HashSet` will reduce the complexity of `contains` from O(n) to O(1):

```
final Set<Long> rollNoList = new HashSet<>();
```

If you can't do this, you may also see some performance gain, at the cost of increased memory usage, by copying the `List` into a `HashSet` before filtering:

```
final Set<Long> rollNumbers = new HashSet<>(rollNoList);
```

but if you have control over the data structure, just use `HashSet` from the beginning.

Comment: In fact, it makes more sense to convert the `List<Long>` to a `Set<Long>` first. This way the call to `ids.contains` will be O(1) and not O(n) in costs. Not doing that is obviously more inefficient.

Comment: This is gonna be funny when he turns in this assignment using this code and he tries to explain what it's doing.

Comment: @rabbitguy I'm generally against suggesting stream-based answers to beginners, but I'd hope it's pretty obvious what this is doing.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, well, I have a feeling that turning in this code will clue the professor into the fact that he didn't do the work himself

Comment: @rabbitguy Then that's his problem. My answers on this website are not meant to be blindly copied and pasted anywhere. They are intended to aid people's understanding.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Good optimisation. I'll edit it in.